# Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.showEditModal is not a function in Vue 3 + Laravel Poject

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

working with Laravel + Vue Js 3 project. in My Tags.vue file I have edit button as well
please see tags.vue file via this link
https://codepen.io/amumodaya/pen/abjqXbV

but when I clicked edit button it is not appearance tag edit page and console encounted following error message
`Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.showEditModal is not a function onClick http://localhost:8000/js/app.js:20386`

`[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler`

**app.js**

```
import ViewUIPlus from 'view-ui-plus'
import 'view-ui-plus/dist/styles/viewuiplus.css'
import 'view-ui-plus/dist/styles/viewuiplus.css'
import common from './common'

createApp({
    components: {
        mainapp,
    }
    
}).use(router).use(ViewUIPlus).mixin(common).mount('#app');
```

how could I fix this problem?

Comment: It's not clear from your code what the issue might be. You need to share the full component. Things to check: if you are using composition API make sure you are returning the `showEditModal` method at the end of the `setup` method. If you are using options API, make sure the `showEditModal` method is in the `methods` object.

Comment: @ChrisStarling I have update my Tags.vue full sourse file

Comment: Can you share the full `Tags.vue` file

Comment: @ChrisStarling yes now you can see full Tags.vue file as well sir

Comment: @ChrisStarling it is dificult upload all tags.vue file

Comment: no any ideas to fix this problem

Comment: The reason for the error is because the `showEditModal` is not recognised by the Vue component. Without seeing the full file I cannot tell you why that is. My first comment shows some common pitfalls that could cause the error but you haven't provided enough information to indicate why you are getting that error.

Comment: @ChrisStarling please see my full tags.vue via code pen link https://codepen.io/amumodaya/pen/abjqXbV

Comment: @ChrisStarling did you see my tags.vue page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `showEditModal` is not inside the `methods` object:

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        ...
    },
    showEditModal() { ... }
    created() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The same applies to `showEditTag` and `showDeletingModal`. You need to move those functions so they are part of the `methods` object, otherwise Vue won't treat them as methods.